# Converting byte array to string value

Tags: powershell

I'm try to return the properties of an image and can't seem to figure out how to convert the PropertyItems value to a string

```
$img = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile('C:\temp\Chart01.jpg')
$img.PropertyItems |
ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_.Id, $_.Value, @{ Expression={[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString( -ExpandProperty $_.Value )} }
}
```

Can someone help get this working and explain a little where I've gone wrong.  I'm sure it is easy (once you know how).

Also, is there any way to convert the number Ids of the properties to the Named values?

Thank you in advance.

Update
I continued trying this and that and trying to find this online (I'm sure I'm not the first to try and do this!) and made a little headway but still stuck on numerous property types

```
$img.PropertyItems | Sort-Object Id | Select-Object -Property Id, Type, Value, @{name="V"; expression={ [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($_.Value)}}
ForEach-Object {
    #https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.propertyitem.type?view=windowsdesktop-5.0
    <#if($_.Type -eq 1){ #array of bytes.
        Write-Host $_.Id, $_.Value, @{ Expression={(new-object System.Text.UTF8Encoding).GetString($_.V)} }
    }#>
    if($_.Type -eq 2){ #null-terminated ASCII string.
     #[System.Text.ASCIIEncoding]::ASCII.GetString( $img.GetPropertyItem(271).Value )
       #Write-Host $_.Id, $_.Value, @{ Expression={(new-object System.Text.UTF8Encoding).GetString($_.V)} }
        Write-Host $_.Id, $_.Value, @{ Expression={(new-object System.Text.UTF8Encoding).GetString($_.V)} }
    }
    if($_.Type -eq 3){ #array of unsigned short (16-bit) integers
        Write-Host $_.Id, $_.Value, @{ Expression={(new-object System.Text.UnicodeEncoding).GetString($_.V)} }
    }
    if($_.Type -eq 4){ #array of unsigned long (32-bit) integers.
        Write-Host $_.Id, $_.Value, @{ Expression={(new-object System.Text.UTF32Encoding).GetString($_.V)} }
    }
    <#if($_.Type -eq 5){ #array of pairs of unsigned long integers. Each pair represents a fraction; the first integer is the numerator and the second integer is the denominator.
        Write-Host $_.Id, $_.Value, @{ Expression={(new-object System.Text.UTF32Encoding).GetString($_.V)} }
    }
    if($_.Type -eq 6){ #array of bytes that can hold values of any data type.
        Write-Host $_.Id, $_.Value, @{ Expression={(new-object System.Text.UTF32Encoding).GetString($_.V)} }
    }
    if($_.Type -eq 7){ #array of signed long (32-bit) integers.
        Write-Host $_.Id, $_.Value, @{ Expression={(new-object System.Text.UTF32Encoding).GetString($_.V)} }
    }
    if($_.Type -eq 10){ #array of pairs of signed long integers. Each pair represents a fraction; the first integer is the numerator and the second integer is the denominator.
        Write-Host $_.Id, $_.Value, @{ Expression={(new-object System.Text.UTF32Encoding).GetString($_.V)} }
    }#>
}
```

Comment: What's currently not working? Are you getting an error, or an incorrect result?

Comment: The different properties have different types and I'm not sure how to convert them from their stored formats to a string value.

I've been working at it and made a little headway

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for:

```
$img = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile('path\to\img.jpg')
$enc = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$img.PropertyItems | Select-Object *,@{n='Value';e={$enc.GetString($_.Value)}} -ExcludeProperty Value
```

```
   Id  Len Type Value                                                                                                                                                     
   --  --- ---- -----                                                                                                                                                     
  256    2    3 5                                                                                                                                                        
  257    2    3 �                                                                                                                                                        
  258    6    3                                                                                                                                                        
  262    2    3                                                                                                                                                          
  274    2    3                                                                                                                                                          
  277    2    3                                                                                                                                                          
  282    8    5   H                                                                                                                                                      
  283    8    5   H                                                                                                                                                      
  296    2    3                                                                                                                                                          
  305   34    2 Adobe Photoshop CC 2017 (Windows)                                                                                                                         
  306   20    2 2017:08:21 18:50:01                                                                                                                                       
36864    4    7 0221                                                                                                                                                      
40961    2    3 ��                                                                                                                                                        
40962    4    4 5                                                                                                                                                        
40963    4    4 �                                                                                                                                                        
20507 5724    1 ���� Adobe_CM �� Adobe d�   �� �            ...                                                                                                      
20515    2    3                                                                                                                                                          
20525    8    5 H                                                                                                                                                        
20526    8    5 H                                                                                                                                                        
20528    2    3                                                                                                                                                          
  513    4    4 �                                                                                                                                                        
  514    4    4 \                                                                                                                                                        
20625  128    3                                                                                           
20624  128    3
```

On *"is there any way to convert the number Ids of the properties to the Named values?"*, I would say yes, you could use a `hashtable` and another calculated property on `Select-Object`. If you edit your answer showing a table with `Id` and `Named Value`, I can edit this answer to show you.

Comment: The Value returns all sorts of type of data and I'm simply wanting to convert it depending on the Type back to plain English.

Comment: @StillLearning I think I see what you mean, see my update. The thing is I have no idea how it was encoded to bytes in the first place so we don't know which encoder to use to convert it to string. If you can figure that out (maybe that's based of the ID Number as you pointed out) I can help you with the code.